# Any program that determines lowest OS required for your application to run?

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system

Alright if my title was not clear enough, I am targeting the Windows OS and just wanted to know if there was some type of program that would let me know what "OS" or higher someone needs to run my application, for example:

```
Example functions used in application:
OpenFile - Minimum Supported Client: Windows XP
BCryptEncrypt - Minimum supported client: Windows Vista
...

Scan completed! Result: Minimum supported client: Windows Vista.
```

I know there are is an application called DependencyWalker but from what I can tell that only shows dependant .dlls. Are there any best practices or methods for determining a good minimum Operating System requirement?

Comment: Application manifest ???

Comment: If only life was this simple...

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: I'd say: No such thing besides knowing what technology(ies) you use. For example an Edge Browser plugin would be limited to an OS that can run Edge. Generally you want to actually test the OS you support before you call it supported too. Any new application I wouldn't even want to worry about testing and suporting in XP.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Telling them the name of an application that does this would be a recommendation, and providing a link to it would be an external resource. The question is off topic according to the link I posted. (And you've got enough experience here to know that name calling and personal insults aren't appropriate here either.)

Comment: I am not at Widows ATM, but doesn't the `properties` window of every executable or some registry entry state somewhere the min. version? Perhaps it would be possible to exploit that.

Comment: I suggested an edit to bring the question more inline with both the spirit and the letter of law... :D If it gets approved.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I understood exactly what you said. I just know it's wrong. There's an entire site devoted to [softwarerecs.se] just because questions like this are off topic. (And the quote I provided says **find or recommend**, BTW.)

Comment: @AustinFrench; It was a nice attempt, but unfortunately your edit makes it more subjective of a question than it actually is.

Comment: @Kupto: I'm certain that not all programs do that, but to be honest I don't recall seeing that in the properties window of *any* executable...

Comment: Hmmm... just a quick elgoog search revealed this URL: http://superuser.com/questions/1060460/how-to-get-from-a-exe-executable-file-the-version-author-publisher-etc-and to me, perhaps it might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such an API checker *could* exist. I'm not aware of any that exists though, and I suspect I know why.

It's almost certainly because it would be wrong too often.

For example, if your program uses `CreateProcess()` to run PowerShell, it would fail on Windows 98, but how would a tool detect that you're calling a nonexistent program? Or, if your program is calling a COM interface that doesn't exist: that wouldn't be visible in the export or import tables, either.  Same with functions that are loaded dynamically at runtime using `GetProcAddress()`.

Note that this doesn't mean the problem is *impossible* to solve in *practical* cases.  However, the program is *impossible* to solve for all cases, and requires some pretty heavy-duty static analysis to work for most practical cases. Only unrealistic cases, like the ones you mentioned, would be trivial.

Comment: Or programs / features that were standard for years and suddenly become optional...

Comment: It's nearly impossible to determine that a program *will* work on a particular version, but at least potentially fairly easy to determine the earliest version on which it had any possibility of working (i.e,. it might or might not work on X, but definitely won't work on anything before X).